# How do I stop the "Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped" message from popping up every three or so seconds?

Tags: google-play-services

Last night I had turned my phone off and on again because my data connection at the moment is pretty poor and I was trying to send a message to a friend through Snapchat. This had worked before, and worked this time too, except now there is a message popping every three or so seconds saying "Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped." I have read another thread on this problem, and tried everything, but nothing worked. I would appreciate all and any help. :)

Comment: Try clearing the cache for Google Play Services and reboot.

Comment: @giucal I have the same problem, but clearing cache and rebooting didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem today. Clearing the cache of Google Play services didn't solve it for me. But clearing all data of Google Play Services, uninstalling its updates, rebooting, installing the updates back and rebooting seems to have made the problem go away.